# How to fit a image in all the empty space using css grid?

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I try to fit my pic in my sidebar of web page but it showing empty space how to fit one image in one row using css grid?
I tried grid_column start 1
And grid column end 3?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score -1):

Define the grid layout for that container and then specify the size and position of the image within that layout.

```html
<div class="grid-container">
  <img src="your-image-url.jpg" class="grid-item">
</div>
```

```css
.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: auto;
}

.grid-item {
  grid-column: 1 / 3;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```